# Spring Not commiting transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have done something like this in my project.
I rollback transaction manually, for that i have inserted try-catch block and manually rolled back transaction in catch block.
Now i am calling method2 from method1 and i am saving object to database in method2() but it does not save object to the database.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
@Scheduled(cron = "0 5 16 * * ?")
public void method1() {

try{
---try block---
}
catch(Throwable t){
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()
                .setRollbackOnly();
method2();
}
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void method2() {
---saving object to database----
someService.update(object);
}
```

I just want to know what could be the possible solution for saving object in method2() on method1()'s faliure.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You are running Method 2 in a required transaction , it will have to be a requires new transaction. In the case of a required the EJB will create a transaction if there is not one already, in the event that you have one the EJB will use the current transaction.

Comment: method2 is using the transaction from method1, so both methods are in the same transaction. When method1 rolls back the transaction, it rolls back the update performed in method2

Comment: @forgivenson - how can i update object in method2() ?

Comment: @user3404577 Are these methods in different classes? If so, doing what Kenneth suggested will work. If they are in the same class, and you are using the default Spring proxy transaction handling, instead of aspectj, then it won't work, because the transactional annotations are only handled when a method is called from another class, and can be rerouted through the proxy.

Comment: @KennethClark - I tried requires_new, but that also had no effect.

Comment: @user3404577 Perhaps you could describe what exactly your program is trying to do here, and we can help you redesign it a bit. Or you could look up how to use aspectj mode for your spring transaction handling.

Comment: @user3404577 , what is the error you are experiencing in `method2()` after you have set the transaction to transaction to REQUIRES_NEW.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that once a transaction is rolled back (as you do before calling method2()) that the transaction is done (as in kaput) and you cannot keep using it and expect to commit.  That would need to be a new transaction (e.g. programmatcally):

```
// transactionManager is your platorm transaction manager usually injected
TransactionTemplate transactionTempate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus arg0) {
                method2();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @dmansifield - should i write this after TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()
     .setRollbackOnly(); ? because method2() is not being called.

Comment: I would think you could put all of this in a method and call it from your exception handler. Unless I misunderstood something, the case you are trying to fix is that method2()'s updates are not committed when called from the exception handler.

Comment: its still not getting called.

Comment: its still not working even after method2() get called.

Comment: Are you using the same EJB session?  In my hibernate based code I have to make sure to get a new session/EntityManager from the EntityManagerFactory inside the new transaction.  The existing session will be tied to the old transaction.  I'm not sure if "session" is the correct word in EJB because we use hibernate specifics, but their entitymanager wraps a session anyway.